# How can I get the ID number of a document added to Firestore?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to add a document to Firestore using Flutter/Dart and then add the ID number that Firestore gives it to a list. I've seen online that an old way would be use codeRef.documentID but this doesn't seem to work and the rest of the code in the places I find this seems to be using deprecated syntax. I was thinking of creating the document name myself which would give the ID number I need but this would not protect against clashes. Is there a way I should be doing this?

```
final codeRef = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('codes').doc().set({
      'name': _codeName,
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[set()](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentReference/set.html) returns a `Future<void>`, so it makes sense that `codeRef.documentID` wouldn't work.  `void` doesn't have any properties.

You will want to get the ID from the [DocumentReference](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentReference-class.html) returned by `doc()` before you write the document.

```
DocumentReference ref = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('codes').doc();
String id = ref.id;
ref.set(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var _result = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('codes').add({
  'name': _codeName});

String id = _result.id
```